# How to consume a restful web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, xamarin.forms

I am trying to consume a simple restful asp.net web API that is locally hosted using Xamarin.

I achieved this using a console application as shown below.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PlayerAuthentication.baseWebAddress = "http://localhost:29100/";

            List<GameScoreObject> scores = PlayerAuthentication.getScores();

                foreach (var item in scores)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Result "+ item.Title +" "+ item.Price);
                }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Here is the get scores method:

```
 static public List<GameScoreObject> getScores( )
            {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var response = client.GetAsync(baseWebAddress + "api/books/").Result;
                    var resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<GameScoreObject>>(
                        new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;
                    return resultContent;
                }
            }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What I would like to do is achieve the same result using Xamarin.Forms. Please assist.

Comment: What issue are you having in the Xamarin.Forms application?

Comment: As you can probably tell I am new to this. I have never done it before so if you could tell me how to do it or where to look it would be great! @JonathonChase

Comment: why don't you look at the linked duplicate?